# How to store NTFS MFT file records in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I have recently written a Python program that resolves an entire Master File Table, you can see it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289308/resolve-an-entire-ntfs-master-file-tables-worth-of-file-records-to-absolute-pat).

I wrote it all by myself, using various online documentations I have found as references.
It is completely working, but in doing so I have found that I have pushed Python to its limits.

There were various performance issues, I know looking up Master File Table like I did is I/O bound, I know I can just load the whole $MFT into memory up-front before parsing, but it is over 2GiB in size...

The biggest issue with the code is with memory usage, it takes over 4GiB to store all parsed entries.

So I would like to reimplement it in C++.

I am learning C++ and have written a few working programs in C++ previously, they do compile but they are all relatively simple. I can already implement most of the logic in C++, but there is a giant obstacle that I cannot overcome: the classes.

Let me show you, below is a small snippet from my script, it defines the classes I use to store parsed MFT File Record in Python:

```py
@patcher
class Record_Header(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Written",
        "HardLinks",
        "In_Use",
        "Directory",
        "Base_Record",
        "Record_ID",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Written", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("HardLinks", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("In_Use", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Directory", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Base_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Record_ID", ctypes.c_uint32),
    )

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Record_Header:
        chunks = struct.unpack("<16xHH2xH8xQ4xL", data[:48])
        flag = chunks[2]
        return cls(
            *chunks[:2], bool(flag & 1), bool(flag & 2), chunks[3] & UINT48, chunks[4]
        )


@patcher
class Data_Run(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("First_Cluster", "Cluster_Count")
    _fields_ = (("First_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint32), ("Cluster_Count", ctypes.c_uint32))


def parse_attribute_name(data: bytes, name_length: int, name_offset: int) -> str:
    return (
        data[name_offset : name_offset + 2 * name_length : 2].decode("utf8")
        if name_length
        else ""
    )


class NonResident_Attribute(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Type",
        "Attribute_ID",
        "Allocated_Size",
        "Real_Size",
        "Attribute_Name",
        "Count",
        "Data_Runs",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Allocated_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Real_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Count", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Data_Runs", ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run)),
    )

    @staticmethod
    def parse_data_runs(data: bytes) -> Generator[Data_Run, None, None]:
        while (size := data[0]) and len(data) > 2:
            count = (size & 15) + 1
            first = (size >> 4) + count
            cluster_count = parse_little_endian(data[1:count])
            starting_cluster = parse_little_endian(data[count:first])
            data = data[first:]
            yield Data_Run(starting_cluster, cluster_count)

    @staticmethod
    def get_data_runs(data: bytes) -> Tuple[int, ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run)]:
        data_runs = list(NonResident_Attribute.parse_data_runs(data))
        l = len(data_runs)
        return l, ctypes.cast((Data_Run * l)(*data_runs), ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run))

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes, data_type: int) -> NonResident_Attribute:
        chunks = struct.unpack("<9xBH2xH16xH6xQQ", data[:56])
        name = parse_attribute_name(data, chunks[0], chunks[1])
        l, data_runs = NonResident_Attribute.get_data_runs(data[chunks[3] :])
        return cls(data_type, chunks[2], *chunks[4:], name, l, data_runs)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[:6]} | {
            "Data_Runs": [self.Data_Runs[i].to_dict() for i in range(self.Count)]
        }

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return ctypes.sizeof(self) + sum(
            ctypes.sizeof(self.Data_Runs[i]) for i in range(self.Count)
        )


def preprocess_resident(data: bytes) -> Tuple[bytes, int, str]:
    name_length, name_offset, attribute_id, data_length, data_offset = struct.unpack(
        "<9xBH2xHLH", data[:22]
    )
    return (
        data[data_offset : data_offset + data_length],
        attribute_id,
        parse_attribute_name(data, name_length, name_offset),
    )


class Standard_Information(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    get_size = get_size
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Attribute_ID",
        "File_Created",
        "File_Modified",
        "Record_Changed",
        "Last_Access",
        "Read_Only",
        "Hidden",
        "System",
        "Attribute_Name",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("_file_created", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_file_modified", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_record_changed", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_last_access", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Read_Only", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Hidden", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("System", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @property
    def File_Created(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._file_created)

    @property
    def File_Modified(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._file_modified)

    @property
    def Record_Changed(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._record_changed)

    @property
    def Last_Access(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._last_access)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Standard_Information:
        data, attribute_id, name = preprocess_resident(data)
        chunks = struct.unpack("<4QL", data[:36])
        flag = chunks[4]
        return cls(
            attribute_id, *chunks[:4], *(bool(flag & i) for i in (1, 2, 4)), name
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return (
            {"Attribute_ID": self.Attribute_ID}
            | {key: to_timestamp(getattr(self, key)) for key in self.__names__[1:5]}
            | {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[5:]}
        )


@patcher
class Attribute_List_Entry(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("Type", "Base_Record", "Attribute_ID", "Attribute_Name")
    _fields_ = (
        ("Type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Base_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Attribute_List_Entry:
        (
            attribute_type,
            name_length,
            name_offset,
            base_record,
            attribute_id,
        ) = struct.unpack("<L2xBB8xQH", data[:26])
        return cls(
            attribute_type,
            base_record & UINT48,
            attribute_id,
            parse_attribute_name(data, name_length, name_offset),
        )


class Attribute_List(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("Attribute_ID", "Attribute_Name", "Count", "List")
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Count", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("List", ctypes.POINTER(Attribute_List_Entry)),
    )

    @staticmethod
    def parse_attribute_list(
        data: bytes,
    ) -> Generator[Attribute_List_Entry, None, None]:
        while len(data) > 26:
            offset = 26 + 2 * data[6]
            yield Attribute_List_Entry.parse(data)
            data = data[((offset + 7) >> 3) << 3 :]

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Attribute_List:
        data, attribute_id, name = preprocess_resident(data)
        attributes = list(Attribute_List.parse_attribute_list(data))
        return cls(
            attribute_id,
            name,
            (l := len(attributes)),
            ctypes.cast(
                (Attribute_List_Entry * l)(*attributes),
                ctypes.POINTER(Attribute_List_Entry),
            ),
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[:3]} | {
            "List": [self.List[i].to_dict() for i in range(self.Count)]
        }

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return ctypes.sizeof(self) + sum(
            ctypes.sizeof(self.List[i]) for i in range(self.Count)
        )


@patcher
class FileName(ctypes.Structure):
    NAMESPACES = ("POSIX", "Win32", "DOS", "Win32+DOS")
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Attribute_ID",
        "Parent_Record",
        "Allocated_Size",
        "Real_Size",
        "Name_Space",
        "File_Name",
        "Attribute_Name",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Parent_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Allocated_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Real_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_name_space", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("File_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @property
    def Name_Space(self) -> str:
        return FileName.NAMESPACES[self._name_space]

    @staticmethod
    def parse_file_name(data: bytes) -> str:
        name_data = data[66 : 66 + 2 * data[64]]
        try:
            return name_data.decode("utf8").replace("\x00", "")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return name_data.decode("utf-16-le").replace("\x00", "")

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> FileName:
        data, attribute_id, attribute_name = preprocess_resident(data)
        parent_record, allocated_size, real_size, namespace = struct.unpack(
            "<Q32xQQ9xB", data[:66]
        )
        return cls(
            attribute_id,
            parent_record & UINT48,
            allocated_size,
            real_size,
            namespace,
            FileName.parse_file_name(data),
            attribute_name,
        )


class File_Record(DotTuple):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ("Header", "Attributes")
    __names__ = __slots__
    parsers = {
        16: Standard_Information,
        32: Attribute_List,
        48: FileName,
    }

    def __init__(self, header: Record_Header, attributes: tuple) -> None:
        self.Header = header
        self.Attributes = attributes

    @staticmethod
    def preprocess_file_record(data: bytes) -> bytes:
        if data[:4] != b"FILE":
            raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

        token = data[48:50]
        if token != data[510:512] or token != data[1022:1024]:
            raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

        update_sequence = data[50:54]
        return data[:510] + update_sequence[:2] + data[512:1022] + update_sequence[2:]

    @staticmethod
    def parse_record_attributes(data: bytes) -> Generator:
        data = data[56:]
        while data[:4] != b"\xff\xff\xff\xff":
            length = parse_little_endian(data[4:8])
            attribute_type = parse_little_endian(data[:4])
            if data[8]:
                if attribute_type in (32, 128):
                    yield NonResident_Attribute.parse(data[:length], attribute_type)
            elif cls := File_Record.parsers.get(attribute_type):
                yield cls.parse(data)

            data = data[length:]

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> File_Record:
        data = File_Record.preprocess_file_record(data)
        return cls(
            Record_Header.parse(data),
            tuple(File_Record.parse_record_attributes(data)),
        )

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return (
            self.__sizeof__()
            + self.Header.get_size()
            + self.Attributes.__sizeof__()
            + sum(attr.get_size() for attr in self.Attributes)
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "Header": self.Header.to_dict(),
            "Attributes": [attr.to_dict() for attr in self.Attributes],
        }
```

The problem is extremely simple, all MFT file records are split into two sections: Header and Attributes.

The attributes can be empty if the header has In-Use flag set to 0, which would be a big problem for me if I want to store it, because it wouldn't be easy to make it into the same class as other records. But I am not interested in deleted files and I would just discard the record.

But then, all file records marked as in-use have different number of attributes and different kinds of attributes.

Some files have only 0x80 $DATA attributes and nothing else, these files have other attributes stored in a separate file that is referenced by the Base_Record field.

Some files have one 0x10 $STANDARD_INFORMATION attribute and one or two $FILE_NAME attributes depending on whether or not the filename is DOS-compatible, files that are too large will have 0x20 $ATTRIBUTE_LIST attribute.

All attributes can have names, and the names obviously have variable lengths. And $FILE_NAME of course stores filenames, which can have even more diverse lengths.

Then attributes that are non-resident will have any number of data-runs that is greater or equal to one...

How can I store all of them in an array or a vector?

To my very limited understanding of C++, C++ is statically typed, and all objects must have a well-defined class, array elements should be homogeneous and should have the same length (but I know I can put strings into a vector), the elements should have the same length to make lookups faster because the bytes of the objects are stored head to tail in sequential order and lookup is simply reading the byte sequence that starts at array start + index * length of one element and ends at that number plus the length of one element...

Obviously these file records are far from homogeneous.

How can I then store them in memory?

There are currently two options that I can think of, both with severe drawbacks.

Option 1: make one class for each and every configuration of the attributes of file records, this can make the array elements homogeneous, but filenames can still be a problem. And this necessitates use of multiple arrays for each of these classes, and will break if there is a configuration that is unexpected...

Option 2: make the base class based on the longest possible configuration, and use pointers for the attributes, fill the empty attributes with the null pointer. For example, make every file record object have references to two $DATA attributes, one $STANDARD_INFORMATION, two $FILE_NAME attributes, and one $ATTRIBUTE_LIST. If the file only has a $DATA attribute, fill all other references with NULL pointer.

Option 2 will waste memory heavily, and will break if the file record has more than two $DATA attributes and pointers are really complicated...

What class should I use to store them in memory in C++?

Comment: Instead of trying to convert Python code that was an approximation of C code to begin with, try writing the code in C++ *from the start*. All the Win32 API examples are in C and the Win32 SDK already contains headers that define the methods and structs you use.

Comment: In fact it's better to start learning C++ properly instead of trying to look at it from a Python point of view. Classes in Python are *very* quirky because they were added after the fact. Classes in C++ are easier and there's no reason to perform any kind of pointer arithmetic to access array items. In fact, it's frowned upon since 1992, when the first edition of `Effective C++` came out

Comment: Do not use python or any other programming language as a guide in writing C++ code.  If you continue on that route, you will write programs that are 1) Inefficient, 2) Buggy, 3) Look weird to a C++ programmer.  You just have to bite the bullet and actually learn C++ from scratch -- C++ is one of the most difficult computer languages out there.